# how to implement viewpager and circleindicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, slideshow

I want to display images on launch screen using Viewpager & use Circle indicator to show position in the slideshow and would also like to add a button at the end image of the slideshow!

Comment: i tried using viewpager and fragment pageradapter but i searched on the internet and found out that viewpager and circle indicator was used along with JSON but i just wanna know is there any way without using JSON??

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) Lib. (ViewPagerIndicator by JakeWharton)

Should do all what you need. Also it is very well coded, so its a nice guide if you want to do this by yourself.

Comment: I had similar requirement and found solution from above library.

Comment: okay. this will be the first thing i am going to do after i wake up. hope this helps me. Thanks

Comment: @SmithThapa Did you have any success so far?

Comment: to be honest i tried to implement but i could not. i am very new to android so could not @oberflansch

Comment: @oberflansch I have successfully done that. I have trained and now i am on my way to learn and develop some kick ass android apps. Thanks once again

Comment: @oberflansch And for this I used AppIntro https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLsavAwYbNAhVIRI8KHdJyD6UQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FPaoloRotolo%2FAppIntro&usg=AFQjCNGOxHDFtiYQKwOYxzGqLKUbuhOMaw&bvm=bv.123325700,d.c2I